# Why does this Haskell code not terminate?

Tags: haskell

Why does the following Haskell code not terminate:

```
foldr (||) True $ repeat False -- never terminates
```

when something like this does:

```
foldr (||) False $ repeat True -- => True
```

To me, it's the second expression that looks to be in more trouble of not terminating. What's wrong with my view of Haskell's lazy evaluation?

Comment: you can always use stepeval for these kinds of problems. it takes a second to decypher, but may be helpful. http://bm380.user.srcf.net/cgi-bin/stepeval.cgi?expr=foldr+%28%7C%7C%29+True+%24+repeat+False

Comment: I wrote stepeval, and it's not evaluating that expression correctly! It has a few bugs, I'm afraid (in this case it forgets the 'let' even though it still needs it)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think your understanding of lazy is correct, but not for `foldr`. Let's look at its "[specification](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:foldr)"

```
foldr f z [x1, x2, ..., xn] == x1 `f` (x2 `f` ... (xn `f` z)...)
```

Then look at your expression

```
foldr (||) True $ repeat False -- never terminates
```

As you see the `True` (`z`) which we are "looking for" to get `||` to terminate won't be reached until the whole list is consumed. And that won't happen as the list is infinite.

This should also explain for the actually terminating example.

Comment: Indeed, I was misunderstanding foldr, not lazy evaluation!

Answer (score 13):

The first expands to `False || (False || (False || ...))`, while the second expands to `True || (True || (True || ...))`.  The second argument to `foldr` is a red herring - it appears in the innermost application of `||`, not the outermost, so it can never actually be reached.

Answer (score 9):

The problem is quite obvious, if you unfold the `foldr` manually:

```
foldr (||) True $ repeat False == False || (False || (False (False || ... True)))
```

So in order to get the final `False`, the code had to evaluate the list till its (nonexistant) end. In your second example, you repeat `True`, thus short-circuit evaluation is possible. Don't expect magic from lazy evaluation!

Comment: You swapped True and False in the unfolding.

Answer (score 3):

A yet another insight for you is that `||` is not commutative in Haskell, it's *biased*:

```
Prelude> undefined || True
*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
Prelude> True || undefined
True
```

So unlike in math, `||` and `flip (||)` are different functions. E.g. compare

`foldr (||) False $ repeat True` and `foldr (flip (||)) False $ repeat True`

The former terminates, but the latter don't.

Comment: Thanks. That is indeed another surprise to me!